VSCode TODO Highlight v2 specifying order of applied highlights
I'm trying to change the color of comments because the default is too dark. I would like all comments in one color, and to further highlight TODO:, FIXME:, and REVIEW: keywords. I have the following keywords, but the RegEx at the bottom ends up overriding all the other highlights. If I move RegEx to the top, it still overrides all the other keywords, and they all appear as #00cccc.
{
    "todohighlight.keywords": [
        "TODO:",
        "FIXME:",
        "REVIEW:",
        {
            "text": "all comments",
            "regex": {
                "pattern": "\\# (.+)"
            },
            "color": "#00cccc",
            "backgroundColor": "transparent",
            "border": "none",
            "isWholeLine": false
        },
    ],
}

I tried using RegEx to exclude the keywords explicitly like ^(?!TODO:).+, but that doesn't work.
How can I highlight normal comments as #00cccc, then highlight TODO:, FIXME:, and REVIEW: using the default settings?

Why would anything be any other color? The instructions are here btw: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wayou.vscode-todo-highlight

Because text matches like TODO: without a color specification should get marked using default highlights.

Are default highlights #00cccc? Doesn't your pattern match TODO etc. comments?

I would like enforced order of priority, so I can specify highlighting TODOs after highlighting everything else.

Sorry, too many unknowns for me. Does it work if you use #TODO instead of # TODO and is that a reasonable workaround? Alternately, make explicit entries for TODO, etc.
